# Beautiful Soup unable to access first tag in find_all list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When using Beautiful Soup find_all() and looping over the results, I can't access the  element.

```
<html>
...
<article post-id="123">Article 1</article>
<article post-id="456">Article 2</article>
<article post-id="789">Article 3</article>
...
</html>
```

```
articles = soup.find_all('article')

for a in articles:
    post_id = a.find('article', {'post-id':True})
    print(post_id)
```

returns None

Based on previous answers I've found on here, I thought the post-id value 123, 456, etc. could be accessed using `post_id['post-id']`

When I print `a` inside the for loop I see the `<article...>` element.

What is the correct way to access the `post-id` value?

Answer (score 1):

To get `post-id=` value, try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<html>
<article post-id="123">Article 1</article>
<article post-id="456">Article 2</article>
<article post-id="789">Article 3</article>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("article[post-id]"):
    print(a["post-id"])
```

Prints:

```
123
456
789
```

---

- `soup.select("article[post-id]")` - selects all `<article>` which contain `post-id=` attribute
- `print(a["post-id"])` - prints value of `post-id=` attribute

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any way to access post-id inside my `articles` loop? The html is a simplified example and I need to get some other data from inside the <article> elements. Your solution will work as a separate loop but I'll need to attach the post-id values to the other data I get from inside <article>.

Comment: @offtheradar Try `post_id = a.get('post-id')` inside your loop

Comment: Thank you @Andrej! That works and is the solution I was looking for.